# Why a PDF file of mail trail has different paragraph font size when saved as PDF in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

I'm using the feature save as pdf in printing dialog of Google Chrome to print the file. Why one of the paragraphs on the file has smaller font than the others? Let's say all paragraphs(but one) has font size of 10, then, there is one that has 9,7. Just one paragraph.

The file itself consists an AOL email trail and messages are in rows, one under another.

Comment: We do not know. We don't even know which PDF file(s) you are referring to.

Comment: Can't share the files. My question is whether text of a pdf may be automstically chnaged by a 3rd party off for pdf. Just one paragraph is smaller. Whybthat happened?

Comment: It could be the pdf itself, depending on what font styles and sizes were specified

Comment: Even if a file was created using printer "Save As pdf" Chrome feature?

Comment: If you can't share those files or an details about them, try with other ones. Or try to reproduce the issue with the same fonts and sizes.